# Splitting tables columns in dataframe into individual csv's

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sample df like this, I'd like to separate by date, ID, and ID_BB_GLOBAL and add column "date" using the respective date for each table on top and make a CSV in format "ID,ID_BB_GLOBAL,Date" columns. Anyone know how to do this pandas?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pznsM.png

```
> 0   2020-01-31 00:00:00                   NaN 2020-02-28 00:00:00  ...                   NaN 2020-12-31 00:00:00                   NaN
3                    ID  ID_BB_GLOBAL().value                  ID  ...  ID_BB_GLOBAL().value                  ID  ID_BB_GLOBAL().value
4           A UN Equity          BBG000C2V541         A UN Equity  ...          BBG00Y2JBWP1         A UN Equity          BBG000C2V541
5         AAL UW Equity          BBG005P7Q8V5       AAL UW Equity  ...          BBG000C2V541       AAL UW Equity          BBG005P7Q8V5
6         AAP UN Equity          BBG000F7RFH6       AAP UN Equity  ...          BBG005P7Q8V5       AAP UN Equity          BBG000F7RFH6
7        AAPL UW Equity          BBG000B9Y5X2      AAPL UW Equity  ...          BBG000F7RFH6      AAPL UW Equity          BBG000B9Y5X2
```

Comment: If you give a data sample in copyable text and show what would be the expected result, then we could help you. Currently I can not even understand what is your input data...

Comment: I'm a little confused by data sample but essentially. I want to splice the data frame by every instance of ID, ID BB GLOBAL and 'date' and create separate csv's for those dataframes.

Comment: You only gave an image. I need something to build a dataframe *on my own system* in order to test for possible ways. So I am asking you to give some rows and columns from your dataframe [This page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pandas/info) contains links showing you how to provide your data.

Comment: With some data, I could give you some code. With no data I cannot tell you more than: 1/ use groupby on the ID, ID BB GLOBAL and 'date' columns, then 2/ iterate the subframes from the GroupBy object and use to_csv on each.

Comment: Attached a snippet above. Thank you so much

Comment: assuming you have your data in a dataframe **df** `df.loc[:,["col1","col2","col3"]].to_csv("subset.csv")`

Comment: @SergeBallesta not sure if this data sample helps.

Comment: It **does** help. It contains copyable data. From there it is possible to build locally a dataframe close to yours and test what can be done with it. It allowed me to post an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my tests, I used that extract from your data (`nan` is of course `np.nan`):

```
pd.DataFrame([['2020-01-31 00:00:00', nan, '2020-02-28 00:00:00', nan, 
               '2020-12-31 00:00:00', nan], 
              ['ID', 'ID_BB_GLOBAL().value', 'ID', 'ID_BB_GLOBAL().value',
               'ID', 'ID_BB_GLOBAL().value'],
              ['A UN Equity', 'BBG000C2V541', 'A UN Equity', 'BBG00Y2JBWP1',
               'A UN Equity', 'BBG000C2V541'],
              ['AAL UW Equity', 'BBG005P7Q8V5', 'AAL UW Equity',
               'BBG000C2V541', 'AAL UW Equity', 'BBG005P7Q8V5'],
              ['AAP UN Equity', 'BBG000F7RFH6', 'AAP UN Equity',
               'BBG005P7Q8V5', 'AAP UN Equity', 'BBG000F7RFH6'],
              ['AAPL UW Equity', 'BBG000B9Y5X2', 'AAPL UW Equity',
               'BBG000F7RFH6', 'AAPL UW Equity', 'BBG000B9Y5X2']],
             index=[0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

It looks like:

```
                     1                     2                    3                     4                    5                     6
0  2020-01-31 00:00:00                   NaN  2020-02-28 00:00:00                   NaN  2020-12-31 00:00:00                   NaN
3                   ID  ID_BB_GLOBAL().value                   ID  ID_BB_GLOBAL().value                   ID  ID_BB_GLOBAL().value
4          A UN Equity          BBG000C2V541          A UN Equity          BBG00Y2JBWP1          A UN Equity          BBG000C2V541
5        AAL UW Equity          BBG005P7Q8V5        AAL UW Equity          BBG000C2V541        AAL UW Equity          BBG005P7Q8V5
6        AAP UN Equity          BBG000F7RFH6        AAP UN Equity          BBG005P7Q8V5        AAP UN Equity          BBG000F7RFH6
7       AAPL UW Equity          BBG000B9Y5X2       AAPL UW Equity          BBG000F7RFH6       AAPL UW Equity          BBG000B9Y5X2
```

As is, it cannot be used as a dataframe because all rows do not contain consistent data:

- first one contains dates
- second one contains what looks like column names
- only the other ones contain actual data

I would first put correct column names from the second row, then split the dataframes in sets of 2 columns. On each item I would add a date column using the date from the first cell, and drop the first two rows. Once this is done, I would concat all the items and set a new index.

In Pandas, it could be:

```
# set the columns from the second row
df.columns = df.iloc[1]
df = df.rename_axis(columns=None, index=None)

# split the dataframe by sets of 2 columns,adding each a date column from the
# first cell and dropping the first 2 rows
dfs = [df.iloc[:, i:i+2].assign(date=pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[0, i])).iloc[2:]
       for i in range(0, len(df.columns), 2)]

# control the first item
print(dfs[0])

# concat the sub-frames
new_df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

The first item is:

```
               ID ID_BB_GLOBAL().value       date
4     A UN Equity         BBG000C2V541 2020-01-31
5   AAL UW Equity         BBG005P7Q8V5 2020-01-31
6   AAP UN Equity         BBG000F7RFH6 2020-01-31
7  AAPL UW Equity         BBG000B9Y5X2 2020-01-31
```

Hmm, looks good...

And the final data frame is:

```
                ID ID_BB_GLOBAL().value       date
0      A UN Equity         BBG000C2V541 2020-01-31
1    AAL UW Equity         BBG005P7Q8V5 2020-01-31
2    AAP UN Equity         BBG000F7RFH6 2020-01-31
3   AAPL UW Equity         BBG000B9Y5X2 2020-01-31
4      A UN Equity         BBG00Y2JBWP1 2020-02-28
5    AAL UW Equity         BBG000C2V541 2020-02-28
6    AAP UN Equity         BBG005P7Q8V5 2020-02-28
7   AAPL UW Equity         BBG000F7RFH6 2020-02-28
8      A UN Equity         BBG000C2V541 2020-12-31
9    AAL UW Equity         BBG005P7Q8V5 2020-12-31
10   AAP UN Equity         BBG000F7RFH6 2020-12-31
11  AAPL UW Equity         BBG000B9Y5X2 2020-12-31
```

Comment: Thanks! I see what this does and is a good output format, how would you go about creating CSV's based off of date? I'm thinking do a sort and groupby function and "to_csv" the groupby result?